# Cannot display Bootstrap Toasts on my site

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, toast

I managed to get Toasts to appear when I clicked a button. The problem is that I have 2 buttons and I want to make one Toast per button appear. How to do this ?

2nd problem, it is written in the documentation that to make the Toasts work, you just have to put this line in JS:

```
$('.toast').toast('show');
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/toasts/

But it doesn't work, instead you have to do a lot of research to finally write a long JS code. Why is it so simmering in the documentation and so complicated in real life ?

I want the Toasts to appear when my site is offline.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr" class="h-100">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body class="d-flex flex-column bg-dark text-white text-center">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-4" id="updateToast">Show update toast</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-4" id="offlineToast">Show offline toast</button>

    <div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 start-50 translate-middle-x mb-3">
      <div id="updateToast" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-repeat text-success" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M11.534 7h3.932a.25.25 0 0 1 .192.41l-1.966 2.36a.25.25 0 0 1-.384 0l-1.966-2.36a.25.25 0 0 1 .192-.41zm-11 2h3.932a.25.25 0 0 0 .192-.41L2.692 6.23a.25.25 0 0 0-.384 0L.342 8.59A.25.25 0 0 0 .534 9z"/>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3c-1.552 0-2.94.707-3.857 1.818a.5.5 0 1 1-.771-.636A6.002 6.002 0 0 1 13.917 7H12.9A5.002 5.002 0 0 0 8 3zM3.1 9a5.002 5.002 0 0 0 8.757 2.182.5.5 0 1 1 .771.636A6.002 6.002 0 0 1 2.083 9H3.1z"/>
          </svg>
          <strong class="me-auto">Mise à jour disponible</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body text-start text-dark">
          Cliquez ICI pour mettre à jour.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="offlineToast" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-wifi-off text-danger" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M10.706 3.294A12.545 12.545 0 0 0 8 3C5.259 3 2.723 3.882.663 5.379a.485.485 0 0 0-.048.736.518.518 0 0 0 .668.05A11.448 11.448 0 0 1 8 4c.63 0 1.249.05 1.852.148l.854-.854zM8 6c-1.905 0-3.68.56-5.166 1.526a.48.48 0 0 0-.063.745.525.525 0 0 0 .652.065 8.448 8.448 0 0 1 3.51-1.27L8 6zm2.596 1.404.785-.785c.63.24 1.227.545 1.785.907a.482.482 0 0 1 .063.745.525.525 0 0 1-.652.065 8.462 8.462 0 0 0-1.98-.932zM8 10l.933-.933a6.455 6.455 0 0 1 2.013.637c.285.145.326.524.1.75l-.015.015a.532.532 0 0 1-.611.09A5.478 5.478 0 0 0 8 10zm4.905-4.905.747-.747c.59.3 1.153.645 1.685 1.03a.485.485 0 0 1 .047.737.518.518 0 0 1-.668.05 11.493 11.493 0 0 0-1.811-1.07zM9.02 11.78c.238.14.236.464.04.66l-.707.706a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0l-.707-.707c-.195-.195-.197-.518.04-.66A1.99 1.99 0 0 1 8 11.5c.374 0 .723.102 1.021.28zm4.355-9.905a.53.53 0 0 1 .75.75l-10.75 10.75a.53.53 0 0 1-.75-.75l10.75-10.75z"/>
          </svg>
          <strong class="me-auto">Vous êtes hors-ligne</strong>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body text-start text-dark">
          Les informations de cette page peuvent être obsolètes.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      document.getElementById("updateToast").onclick = function() {
        var toastElList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.toast'))
        var toastList = toastElList.map(function(toastEl) {
          return new bootstrap.Toast(toastEl)
        });
       toastList.forEach(toast => toast.show());
      };

      document.getElementById("offlineToast").onclick = function() {
        var toastElList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.toast'))
        var toastList = toastElList.map(function(toastEl) {
          return new bootstrap.Toast(toastEl)
        });
       toastList.forEach(toast => toast.show());
      };
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Is the problem about showing the toast or is it about triggering the event handlers?

Comment: Why are you using those event handlers if you want to determine if the **website** is online or not?

Comment: @Quentin I want to display a toast if the site is offline. But it doesn't show up. Even if I take the example from the documentation, it doesn't work.

Comment: Stop. Look at my comment. Focus on determining what the problem is. Is the event handler firing and the code to display the toast not working? Or is the event handler not firing so the code to display the toast is never called. You need to understand what your problem is before you can solve it.

Comment: @Quentin I updated my question.

Comment: re edit: When I click that button it gives me an error message. Have you investigated that error? It is complaining about a line of code that I don't understand why you included.

Comment: @Quentin I don't see an error in the console. On my site it works but it triggers the 2 Toasts with a button http://mathieulebert.fr/toasts/

Answer (score 2):

Follow below snippet, I hope you will find where you are missing to put element for toast.

```js
var idCounter = 1;
$(document).on('click', '.show-toast', function(){
  var toastHTML = `<div id="newtoast`+idCounter+`" class="toast" role="alert" data-delay="3500">
      <div class="toast-header">
        <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
        <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap `+idCounter+` </strong>
        <small class="text-muted">just now</small>
        <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="toast-body">
        See? Just like this.
      </div>
    </div>`;
    $('#toast-container').prepend(toastHTML);
    $('#newtoast'+idCounter).toast('show')
    idCounter+=1;
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<!-- Position Set Here for Toast -->
<div class="p-3" style="position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; min-width:300px; min-height: 200px;" id="toast-container">
  <!-- Then put toasts within -->
</div>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary show-toast">Show Toast</button>
```

Comment: Thanks but it shouldn't work like that. The HTML code should be in the HTML page and I JS should just do `$('.toast').toast('show');`